# VBA code If condition not satisfying, Stlll entering the loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have IF Condition as below.
Here EntitySum is 1. Though the condition is not satisfying, it is enterign into If loop.

```
    Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim ColCount As Integer
Dim m, x As Integer
Dim EntitySum As Double
RowCount = Worksheets("Contribution").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 4
ColCount = Worksheets("Entities").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 4

m = 4

'outer loop for Rows
Do
EntitySum = 0
x = 6
m = m + 1
    'inner loop for Columns
    Do
    x = x + 1
    EntitySum = EntitySum + Worksheets("Contribution").Cells(m, x).Value
    Loop Until x = ColCount + 6
    If EntitySum <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "The Entity Contribution at Row " & m & " is not 100%. Please Fix it to proceed further."
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop Until m = RowCount + 4
```

[image]

Is it any issue with VBA?

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks,
Rita

Comment: How have you defined `EntitySum`?

Comment: If you have defined it as `String/Variant` then try this `If Val(Trim(EntitySum)) <> 1 Then`

Comment: Yes I defined EntitySum. Dim EntitySum As Double

Comment: Hmm this is strange or maybe I am missing something very obvious

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you. Not sure what it is.... But your code helped me Val(Trim(EntitySum)). All the cells are of percentage type. But no clue. If you post, down below, i will accept it as answer. May help someone else as an accepted answer in future.

Comment: Is it really `ColCount = Worksheets("Entities").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 4` or should it be `ColCount = Worksheets("Entities").UsedRange.Columns.Count - 4`? Just wondering because of the name of the variable.

Comment: Can you put this inside the `If` block: `MsgBox (EntitySum & (EntitySum = 1))`? Just curious to see how that displays...

Comment: That's slightly surprising... Ok do this for me.. Keep `If EntitySum <> 1 Then` as it is and change `EntitySum = EntitySum + Worksheets("Contribution").Cells(m, x).Value` to `EntitySum = EntitySum + Val(Worksheets("Contribution").Cells(m, x).Value)` NOw try it

Comment: Could it be a floating point issue. Maybe the editor rounds it when displaying but the comparision is done on the real value that might be something like 0.99999999999999...  If you try `Round(EntitySum, 4) <> 1` (I took 4, you can change it to whatever number after the decimal you want)

Comment: @litelite: yup that is the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is even though your screenshot shows that the value of `EntitySum = 1`, it is not. Here is a simple way to replicate your problem

In cell `A1` type this number `0.00000000000000001`. You will see that Excel automatically formats it as `1E-17`

Now Try this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim EntitySum As Double

    EntitySum = 1 + Range("A1")

    If EntitySum <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "A"
    End If
End Sub
```

Now `EntitySum` is definitely not equal to `1` but if you hover your mouse over that variable, it will show it as `1`. It is a floating point issue. Excel is not able to handle such large numbers and hence it gives a problem.

To understand why it is behaving like that in your case, you will have to check the cells `Worksheets("Contribution").Cells(m, x).Value` and see what kind of values do they have.

[image]